# Can we have language define per user or group or org?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I wish to check whether we can restrict the supported languages listed in the *language* portlet based on the user organization or group.

We have a page with the language portlet which is configured with the languages "English", "French", "German" etc

We have users:

- German users

  - Belong to *org1* from *Germany*
  - When this type of user visits our page, he should see "English" and "Germin" in the language portlet only.
- Other users

  - Belong to *org2* from global ops
  - When this type of user visits our page, he should see all configured languages.

Can we achieve this with native Liferay or do we need to use a hook to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the language portlet uses the portlet preferences to store the selected languages (see `/html/portlet/language/init.jsp`) and that portlet declares `preferences-owned-by-group` (see `/WEB-INF/liferay-portlet.xml`) it means that all users see the same list of languages.

If you want to change that you will either have to write a hook (make the necessary modifications in `/html/portlet/language/init-ext.jsp` then), create your own portlet, or you implement that feature in your theme. The later is a common scenario anyway, if the demanded designs don't match the ones provided by the language portlet.

Comment: Thanks Tobais, I guess this is one of the solution. As of now, we will go with the default as that seems to be simpler. 

On the contrary, I think we can create a custom portlet which seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Liferay 6.2 you can define the languages per organization or community site. I guess you've set the available languages through portal-ext.properties or via the control panel.

At "site settings - display settings" you can limit the available languages. You can change these languages for every site.

Comment: Thanks Michel, but this would work on the site level, but I am interested on the "my profile" level which seems to be outside the scope of the site and this goes on portal level. Please correct me if I am wrong!